# Changing an <a> tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change an anchor tag from this

```
<a href="#" id="masini">Mașini <i class="bi bi-caret-right"></i></a>
```

to this

```
<a href="#" id="masini">Mașini <i class="bi bi-caret-down"></i></a>
```

when the screen gets smaller. Basically to be responsive. I need to use javascript btw.

I tried the code bellow but it's not working.

```
if(window.innerWidth < 1130px)
        {
            var replace = "Mașini"
            replace += "<i class="bi bi-caret-down"></i>";
            document.getElementById("masini").innerHTML = replace;
        }
```

Comment: Why not use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)?

Comment: What is the reason to use javascript for this and not the inbuilt css media? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/width

Comment: `document.querySelector('#masini i').classList.replace('bi-caret-right', 'bi-caret-down')`-  but you really should consider using CSS media queries, that's what they are for.

Comment: I know how to change the design with @media but not HTML code. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to do the following:

```js
if (window.innerWidth < 1130) {
  document.getElementById("masini").className = "bi bi-caret-down";
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Mașini <i id="masini" class="bi bi-caret-right"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend targeting the `<i>` element and changing it's class:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 1130) {
    const iElement = document.querySelector("#masini i");
    iElement.classList.replace("bi-caret-right", "bi-caret-down");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delimit your double quotes or wrap with single quotes.

```
replace += '<i class="bi bi-caret-down"></i>';
```

OR:

```
replace += "<i class=\"bi bi-caret-down\"></i>";
```